# Counting divisible numbers in array based on user input

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am just starting out in C++ and here is the issue I am having. I need to write a program that will create a 2d array and then allow the user to input a number, from there I need to count and list all the number in that array that are evenly divisible by the user input. I have not started the list portion of the code yet, but the issue I am having is that the counting function I am trying to use is dividing by zero so it will not run. Here is what I have so far and any help will be greatly appreciated

```
void fillArray(int ar [][10], int size);
void printArray(int ar [][10], int size);
int getDivisible (int a [][10], int size, int num);


int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int) time(0));
    int ar[10][10];
    int count = 0;
    fillArray(ar, 10);
    printArray(ar, 10);

    int num;
    cout << "Enter a number to divide by" << endl;
    cin >> num;

    getDivisible(ar, 10, count);
    cout << " There are " << count << " evenly divisible numbers. They are : " << endl;

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

void fillArray(int ar [][10], int size)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
        {
            ar[row][col] = rand() % 101;
        }

    }

}

void printArray(int ar [][10], int size)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
        {
            cout << ar[row][col] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int getDivisible(int ar [][10], int size, int num )
{

    int count = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
        {
            if ((ar[row][col]) % num == 0)
                count++;
        }

    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

```
getDivisible(ar, 10, count);
```

You didn't mean to pass `count` in there, did you?

Because when you get here, in the `getDivisible` function:

```
if ((ar[row][col]) % num == 0)
```

That's a problem, because `num` in `getDivisible` is `count` from `main`, which is `0`.